# definition/implementation question in c#

Tags: c#, plugins, runtime, implementation, definition

I am trying create such a plugin architecture that;
**IPlugin**: an interface that all plugins must implement.
**NormalPlugin**: a normal plugin.
**ComplexPlugin**: a plugin which, beside implementing the base methods, has some custom methods.
**HostApp**: an app that knows what an IPlugin is.

currently the host app will have ComplexPlugin at compile-time and will load the NormalPlugin dynamically. That's because host needs to have definitions in ComplexPlugin so it can call it's custom methods.
**1)** Are there any better methods for achieving this? because adding some plugins as reference to the host app at compile-time looks a little lame to me.

**2)** I tried using:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   object CallCustomMethod(string methodName, object[] parameters);
}
```

but still, if CallCustomMethod returns a complex type, the app will need to know that complex type to cast to.
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329399/best-practices-for-implementing-an-addin-addon-plugin-strategy

Answer (score 0):

If the the app never calls ComplexPlugIn's custom methods other than through your CallCustomMethod function, then it seems to me that you shouldn't ever need to cast to a ComplexPlugIn.

IPlugIn foo = (IPlugIn)myComplexObject.CallCustomMethod("GenerateNewComplexPlugIn", new object[] { 0 });
foo.CallCustomMethod("AnotherComplexMethod", null);

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
my problem is about knowing the return type of CallCustomMethod. it may return a ComplexData class/struct which is defined in ComplexPlugin. I tried to write the same type ComplexData also in the host app. but when i try to cast it compiler says: "can't convert the type ComplexData to ComplexData" :)

Comment: This particular problem could be resolved by defining ComplexData in a separate class library and including a reference to this library in both HostApp and ComplexPlugIn. This would seem to make sense from the point-of-view of decoupling the plug-in from the host app, which would seem to be the whole purpose of using plug-ins.

Without knowing the "big picture" it's difficult to say whether the overall approach is good or bad....

Comment: thanks Andrew. your suggestion looks like the best solution for the problem.